# How is this problem called?

Tags: terminology, optimization

I have a set of integers $\{8, 8, 6\}$. I want to know if It is possible to get $21$ by adding a subset of them. I would like to know how is the problem called so that I can google it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the [Subset Sum Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).

Answer (score 7):

Your question is slightly flawed: $\{8,8,6\}$ is not a set of integers, because it contains a repetition. (Or rather, it is a set of integers, but it only contains the two elements $8$ and $6$.)

If you really did mean "set of integers", then rattle's answer is correct. If you meant "sequence of integers", as suggested by your example, then this is the [Knapsack Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). The Subset Sum Problem is a special case of the Knapsack Problem.

Answer (score 2):

This "set" is an example of what is sometimes called a "multiset": it allows one member (in this case 8) to have multiple memberships in it rather than only one.

You can't get an odd number such as 21 by adding even numbers.